# If the arithmetic mean between a and b is $\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$ then n is

Tags: sequences-and-series

We can equate this to $\frac{a+b}{2}$

Doing relevant calculations I finally get $$a^n=b^n$$
$$a=b$$

But this isn’t helping me find n. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer :**

$$a^n = b^n \implies \left(\frac ab\right)^n=1\implies  \left(\frac ab\right)^n =  \left(\frac ab\right)^0 \implies \boxed{n=0}$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $a$ to equal $b$. Note that not only does $n=0$ work because $x^0=1,\,x^1=1$, but$$\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}\implies 0=2(a^{n+1}+b^{n+1})-(a^n+b^n)(a+b)=(a^n-b^n)(a-b),$$and with $a\ne b$ this requires $a^n=b^n$ to instead be achieved with $n=0$.

Comment: I believe that The OP had also reached the fact that $a^n=b^n$.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Unfortunately, the OP erroneously concluded $a=b$, a case in which any $n$ would work.

Comment: That's exactly why he asked for the help as he believed that it was incorrect.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Then my answer should make the error clear.